# how to run docker run using Go Sdk for docker?

Tags: docker, go

I want to run the below docker command 
`docker run ajaycs14/hello-world -p 1527:80 -d`.

How to achieve above using [Docker Go SDK](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/api/types)?

Sample code to run an image is below, which from official document, how to modify below code to take the options for port and detached mode etc. Please help me in modifying below code to work for above command(`docker run ajaycs14/hello-world -p 1527:80 -d`) ?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "os"

  "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
  "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
  "github.com/docker/docker/client"
  "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
  ctx := context.Background()
  cli, err := client.NewEnvClient()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  imageName := "bfirsh/reticulate-splines"

  out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)

  resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
    Image: imageName,
  }, nil, nil, "")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(resp.ID)
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the method `ContainerCreate` the third parameter is [HostConfig](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/api/types/container#HostConfig) that you need to use. If you are interested in setting ports then you should take a look at `PortBindings` field. Also you need to specify exposed ports for container. You can do this by providing `ExposedPorts` into [container configuration](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/api/types/container#Config) (second parameter).
And I assume that you container will be started in a `daemon` mode by default because you are using API instead of `cli` tool.

Here is a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := client.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image:        "mongo",
        ExposedPorts: nat.PortSet{"8080": struct{}{}},
    }, &container.HostConfig{
        PortBindings: map[nat.Port][]nat.PortBinding{nat.Port("8080"): {{HostIP: "127.0.0.1", HostPort: "8080"}}},
    }, nil, "mongo-go-cli")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

And in the output for `docker ps --all` I can see my port: `PORTS 127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp, 27017/tcp`

Comment: yes, the container is started in daemon mode.  It would be helpful if you provide the example code.

Comment: `resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
    Image: imageName,
  },  &container.HostConfig{
   PortBindings: {"9300:80"},
  }, nil, "")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }`  I am trying this, but not working