# How to configure the env vars , net name, exposed port and volumns when running a docker container in go sdk

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to use the go SDK to run a docker container. In CLI, the docker can be run by

```
docker run -d \
-e myvar1=myval1 \
-e myvar2=myval2 \
--name=myname \
--hostname=myhost \
--net=mynet \
-p 12345:12345 -p 8080:8080  \
-v "my/path/to/data1"  \
-v "my/second-path/to/data2" \
mydocker/image_name:latest command1 \
command2 \
command3
```

I wonder how to find the go SDK equivalent for this cli command. I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45431649/17391507) but I'm still confused about the setting for env vars, network, columns and also multiple exposed ports.

Comment: Start by writing code to run the container without accounting for the switches.  Then, look in the documentation to figure out how to configure each switch.    You have a great post linked; there's no reason you can't provide some code along with this question if you're still stuck.  https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ContainerCreate

Answer (score 0):

You have a more complete example with [`interiorem/stout/isolate/docker/container.go`##`newContainer()`](https://github.com/interiorem/stout/blob/33f77bd87aa5b5e541442c660570526427cf8975/isolate/docker/container.go#L51) which does set `env map[string]string` in the old [`docker/engine-api` `container.Config`](https://github.com/interiorem/stout/blob/33f77bd87aa5b5e541442c660570526427cf8975/vendor/github.com/docker/engine-api/types/container/config.go#L14) structure.
These days, you would use [`moby/moby/api/types/container/config.go`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/api/types/container/config.go#L37-L54).

But in both cases (old and new dependencies), you set environment variables by initializing a Config struct with a map of "environment name"/"environment value" in the `Env` field.